# easytimer.js auto resets when the seconds pass 59 and above

Tags: javascript

Here is the JSFiddle and demo code I made:

https://jsfiddle.net/perezdev/f7o2hjuy/14/

```
$("#start").click(function() {
  var timeToElapse = 59;

  var timer = new Timer();
  timer.start();
  timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
    var time = timer.getTimeValues();
    if (time.seconds > timeToElapse) {
      $('#hit').html('hit');

      timer.pause();
    } else {
      var val = timeToElapse - time.seconds;
      $('#countdown').html(val);
    }
  });
});
```

The idea is that I should be able to set `timeToElapse` to any value so that I can update a label with the count down. When the time elapses, a label should update with the value "hit."

On the JSFiddle, if you update the counter to 58 or below, the label updates and the timer pauses. But 59 above and it never hits. It just autoresets.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getTotalTimeValues()` instead of `getTimeValues()`.

From the [doc](https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/#gettingTimeValuesExample):

> The `getTimeValues()` method returns the time values in *clock* format. For example, every 60 seconds the seconds counter will be set to 0 and 1 minute will be added to the minutes counter. The `getTotalTimeValues` method returns the total of the counters. For example, if the counter has counted 2 minutes, there will be 120 seconds in the seconds counter.